# How to configure Envers with @OneToMany and @EmbeddedId on the Many side

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I have a `User` entity and a `UserCompanyRole` entity. The `UserCompanyRole` has a composite primary key. Each `User` can have multiple roles. I know composite primary keys should be avoided and I have actually replaced it with an id column but I still would like to know if it's my code that's the issue or Envers. The result of the code below is an error at start time. Any idea what's wrong?:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
> default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
> domain.usercompany.UserCompanyRole_AUD column: user_id (should be
> mapped with insert="false" update="false")

File `User.java`

```java
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true, modifiedColumnName = "user_company_roles_mod")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@AuditMappedBy(mappedBy = "user")
private List<UserCompanyRole> userCompanyRoles = new ArrayList<>();
```

File `UserCompanyRole.java`

```java
@EmbeddedId
private UserCompanyRoleId userCompanyRoleId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("userId")
@Audited
private User user;
```

File `UserCompanyRoleId.java`

```java
@Embeddable
public class UserCompanyRoleId implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "company_id")
private Long companyId;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

@Column(name = "role")
private String role;
```

Comment: Which version of hibernate/envers do you use?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to audit `User` and `UserCompanyRole` with composite primary key aka `UserCompanyRoleId`.

I have updated `'role'` value for specific `'user'` and seen that `'user_user_company_roles_history'` table got persisted new record.

Ping me if you want me to share the project.

> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.12
>
> > org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.15.Final

User.java

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "`user`")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User extends BaseEntity {

  private String name;

  @OneToMany
  private List<UserCompanyRole> userCompanyRoles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

UserCompanyRole.java

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserCompanyRole {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserCompanyRoleId userCompanyRoleId;
}
```

UserCompanyId.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class UserCompanyRoleId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "company_id")
    private Long companyId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
}
```

Comment: you don't have an inverse (parent) reference to user? or `JoinColumn` definitions?

Comment: hmm... how do I tell hibernate to generate the FK constraint (for the vanilla, not aud)? (yes, don't use hibernate generation in production, but it's useful for testing, and I'd prefer consistency)

Comment: `@JoinColumn`: (Optional) Used to specify or control the generation of a foreign key constraint when table generation is in effect. If `@JoinColumn` element is not specified, the persistence provider's default foreign key strategy will apply. Which means that is not required to create FKs. `@ManyToOne/OneToMany/OneToOne` etc are already providing JoinColumn effect by default.

Comment: I'm looking at the SQL generated, there's no statement to add a foreign key constraint. hibernate might make a join, but that's not what an FK does.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to map User with insert = "false" update = "false" since where you have it set is in the User entity.

With your code, you would have two user_id in the UserCompanyRole entity, the one of the EmbeddedId and the one of the audited field, as the one you will use for the queries is the one of the id, note the one of the audited field as insert = "false" update = "false".

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't help. Isn't that what `@MapsId("userId")` is for? As you can see in the error, `UserCompanyRole` entity is not the issue, but the Audit one Envers uses: `UserCompanyRole_AUD`. I'm still not sure if Envers doesn't handle `@AuditMappedBy` together with composite keys or I'm mapping something wrong

Answer (score -1):

I've run into this problem before with similar relationships as what you've described above. I don't think it's related to Envers, as I'm not using Envers, and yet I was seeing similar exceptions to what you're seeing. I suppose you could test this by removing the @Audited and @AuditMappedBy annotations temporarily and seeing if you get a similar exception for UserCompanyRole vs. UserCompanyRole_AUD?

To avoid the "Repeated column in mapping" error you might want to try the following:

1. Remove the @JoinColumn annotation from User.userCompanyRoles
2. Move the removed @JoinColumn annotation to UserCompanyRole.user
3. If the above step does not work, convert the UserCompanyRole @JoinColumn to a @JoinFormula like so:

```
@EmbeddedId
private UserCompanyRoleId userCompanyRoleId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("userId")
@JoinFormula(value = "user_id", referencedColumnName= "<user pk column name>")
@Audited
private User user;
```

The formula approach keeps Hibernate from adding another "user_id" column to the mapping.

I'm assuming User has a simple Id/primary key, as it wasn't mentioned. If it too is compound, you'll need something like the following:

```
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = {
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "tid", referencedColumnName = "tid")),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "delegate_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
                    updatable = false, columnDefinition = ENTITY_ID_DEF,
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_delegation_identity")))
    })
```